# Calling global function in Riot.js expression

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I am trying to call a function declared in the global namespace from an expression in Riot.js.

This does not work:

```
<strong>Created { getDateString(item.created) } by { item.creator }</strong>
```

I *can* call the global `moment()` function (from moment.js):

```
<strong>Created { moment(item.created) } by { item.creator }</strong>
```

The overall JavaScript file containing this function *is* loaded... if I call getDateString() from `this.on('mount')` it works:

```
this.on('mount', function() {
    getDateString(new Date());
});
```

I don't really understand how namespacing works in Riot.js, and so I can't figure out why my call to getDateString() is failing in the expression but succeeding in the mount function. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is `getDateString()` defined at global actually? See this example. It works fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/qpJ3yYmTHFJbbdpFQCgI?p=preview

Comment: turns out I was trying to pass a variable that didn't exist, so the function wasn't being called because JS was erroring out. once I fixed that, the right function did get called.

Comment: I generally try to make all the things I use in the html portion of the code local to the tag, either by making a function that calls something else, or by using a mixin.   It tends to make the code work better over the long run, because it makes all the complex logic 'normal javascript' and I never have to guess where a function I'm calling might be 6 months later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your `globalFunction()` is declared at global. The scope of `<script>` tag inside the tag definition is not global. Take care about it.

```
<my-tag>
  <p>{ someGlobalFunction(message) }</p><!-- will work -->
  <p>{ localFunction1(message) }</p><!-- won't work -->
  <p>{ localFunction2(message) }</p><!-- will work -->
  <p>{ localFunction3(message) }</p><!-- will work -->

  <script>
    this.message = 'world'

    // Not reachable from the template
    function localFunction1 (arg) {
      return 'Hello ' + arg + '!'
    }

    // Reachable because this is the same as localFunction3
    localFunction2 (arg) {
      return 'Hello ' + arg + '!'
    }

    // Reachable from the template
    this.localFunction3 = function(arg) {
      return 'Hello ' + arg + '!'
    }.bind(this)
  </script>
</my-tag>
```

Comment: That's great clarification. Turns out this wasn't my issue, but this definitely helps clarify some other things I was seeing. Thanks!

Comment: Copy/paste mistake, I was passing a variable that didn't exist and Javascript didn't know how to do that. Once I changed the parameter, the function was called as expected.